# Page component renders when user is not authenticated in vue router

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router

I check user authentication at router.beforEach in my router.js as follows:

```
router.beforeEach((to, _, next) => {
  const useAuthStore = useAuth();

  // Check loggged in status
  const isLoggedIn = isUserLoggedIn();

  console.log("is logged in", isLoggedIn);
  // Change layout when path is home
  if (to.path === "/home" && !isLoggedIn) {
    appContentLayoutNav.value = AppContentLayoutNav.Landing;

    // Update logo
    appLogo.value = h("div", {
      innerHTML: logo,
    });
  } else {
    appContentLayoutNav.value = AppContentLayoutNav.Vertical;
    // Update logo
    appLogo.value = h("div", {
      innerHTML: logo,
    });
  }

  if (to.path !== "login" && !isLoggedIn) {
    console.log("tokens expired");
    useAuthStore.removeTokens();
    // Redirect user to the login page if not authenticated.

    next();
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

But, when i remove the token from localstorage and then reload the page, the active page renders and then the login page appears!.
I want to know the main reason of displaying active page again .
I am seeking to prevent to display the active page , and just show the login page, after authentication failed.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to redirect the user to the login page in case he/she is not logged-in - you should use `next("/login")` rather than `next()`

```js
if (to.path !== "/login" && !isLoggedIn) 
{
    console.log("token expired");
    useAuthStore.removeTokens();

    // Redirect user to the login page if not authenticated.
    next("/login");
} 
else 
{
    next();
}
```